# VC++ Error: error C1083: Cannot open source file: '=0x0401': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

**Summary:**

Maybe at a glance, it is a common question, but in my case, I don't reach for an answer.

I downloaded a sample [hooking program from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC), it has three projects, two of them are dll, and one is the main project that use this two dll to perform its primary goal. But when I want to compile it, a project named: `KeyBoardHookLib` cause an error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open source file: '=0x0401': No such file or directory
```

**Question:**

It is a common question, I do all available solution, but the problem remains.  Could please anyone takes a look at this project and give me an answer to compile it.

Comment: To me somehow the project file is corrupted and the expression =0x0401 is listed as a c++ file. And I did not down vote.

Comment: what does 0x0401 mean?

Comment: Again for some odd reason "=0x0401" is listed as a c++ file in the project. This must be a visual studio bug in the code that converts Visual Studio 6 projects to VS2010. Michael gave the solution.

Comment: Also I believe 0x0401 is used for NT version that the application is targeted to. I am unsure how the conversion messed that up. However Visual Studio 6 is 15 years old now. I assume MS does not spend a lot of time testing conversions back to ancient versions of their compilers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the comments of codeproject :](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC?msg=4682026#xx4682026xx)

> After your converting to VS2010 solution, precompiled header should be changed from /Yu to /Yc in all 3 projects. Delete '=0x0401' in KeyBoardHookLib.vcxproj.